# Facebook Markup Language & .NET MVC 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-2, fbml

I am creating a .NET MVC (1.0) facebook application using FBML.  Everything is working like expected.  However, if I simply change the project to reference the System.Web.Mvc 2.0 assembly, the application stops working.  No exceptions are thrown (it makes it through the controller class fine) but nothing is rendered on the page?  Any ideas?

Edit #2:  If I strip away all FBML, I still having nothing rendered.  Now I've stripped it down to the following.  Again, this works great when I reference the Mvc 1.0 assembly

Index.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
<asp:Content ID="indexContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
Inside Index
 </asp:Content>
```

Site.Master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>
Master Page
```

Home Controller

```
[FacebookAuthorization(IsFbml = true)] 
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var api = this.GetApi();
  ViewData["userId"] = api.Session.UserId;
  return View();
}
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing what the controller does? What's the return type? If it renders view, what's the view doing?

On another note, your question says you're creating .NET MVC (1.0) app, but you're referencing MVC 2.0 assembly. I'm sure you might be doing everything right, but there's some confusion here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the assembly binding in the web.config file. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542587/adding-bindingredirect-element-in-web-config-when-upgrading-from-asp-net-mvc-1-to) question for details.